# Basis with polynomials vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vectors, change-of-basis

Let $\mathbb{R}_2[t]$ be the space of polynomials of one variable with real coeﬃcients and degree less than or equal to two. 
Show that $p_1(t) = 1−t, p_2(t) = 1−t^2, p_3(t) = t$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}_2[t]$.

Also, compute the coordinates of $q_1(t) = 2−5t + t^2$ and $q_2(t) = 3−6t + t^2$ with respect to such basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Show that $p_1(t) = 1−t, p_2(t) = 1−t^2, p_3(t) = t$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}_2[t]$

Depending on what you know and what you are allowed to use, this can be shown easily or it can require a bit more effort. If you know $\mathbb{R}_2[t]$ is three-dimensional, it suffices to show that $\left\{ p_1,p_2,p_3\right\}$ is linearly independent, so:
$$\forall t : \alpha \left( 1−t \right)+\beta \left(1−t^2\right)+\gamma t = 0 \implies \alpha = \beta = \gamma = 0$$
If you explicitly need to show that $\left\{ p_1,p_2,p_3\right\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}_2[t]$, then you need to show that you can solve the following system for $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ in terms of $a,b,c$ so that the equality holds for all $t$:
$$at^2+bt+c = \alpha \left( 1−t \right)+\beta \left(1−t^2\right)+\gamma t$$

> Also, compute the coordinates of $q_1(t) = 2−5t + t^2$ and $q_2(t) = 3−6t + t^2$ with respect to such basis.

For example, for $q_1$, solve for $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$:
$$\forall t : \alpha \left( 1−t \right)+\beta \left(1−t^2\right)+\gamma t = 2−5t + t^2 \iff
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\alpha + \beta & = & 2 \\
-\alpha+\gamma & = & -5 \\
-\beta & = & 1
\end{array}\right. \iff \ldots$$
Likewise for $q_2$.